# Automatic/Scheduled iOS Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm very new to iOS development. I currently have a fair chunk of the app I want to make done but I'm just now trying to figure out how to implement remote push notifications. I essentially need these to happen automatically and if a certain condition is met.

Basically, I'm using a weather api to do some stuff in my app, and eventually I want to send each user a notification depending on the weather for their location+some other factors (those other factors will be stored in the database, which has not been set up yet) while the app is closed. Would I need server side code to do something like that? And would it simply have to execute once every 24 hours (or some interval of time) for each user?

I've looked at several tutorials about how to set up push notifications but I can't figure out what I need to do to make this work the way I need it to so some explanation would be great. And what service would be best for this (like aws/lambda, firebase, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications can be very tricky and are more on the advanced side of iOS Development, it can be a long and complicated process. However, fear not! [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) has an excelent tutorial that can help you implement Apple Push Notifications.

As for sending push notification out at regular intervals, it depends on your type of server. I would normally recommend using a cron job to schedule regular intervals for your push notifications, as I have had good experiences with using them for just this purpose but since you are using firebase which has no cron jobs or any type of scheduling options, you will probably have to use a third party api like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/schedule/).

Otherwise, [Google's Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine) can provide you with ability to schedule tasks for whatever you want to accomplish!

Comment: Thanks! I actually haven't yet set up my database, what would recommend doing to make the cron jobs part of this easy?

Comment: I would recommend a ubuntu operating system on your server since ubuntu supports cron jobs plus lots of other useful features and using a MySQL database for a backend. If you don't already, you will need to pick up a good server side language to communicate with the MySQL database such as PHP or Ruby on Rails and SQL of course. All of these tools can be provided to you through a hosting company such as (hostgator) https://www.hostgator.com/ or (bluehost) https://www.bluehost.com/

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, would you mind giving it the green checkmark? :)